# Graphs of continuous functions denote subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

The set of all continuous functions form a vector space but I am not being able to proceed from here

Comment: If you know $f$ at the points ${k \over 3}$ for $k=0,1,2,3$ then you know all of $f$. Find an invertible linear map $M:\mathbb{R}^4 \to S$. Take a wild guess at the dimension.

Comment: Can it be not done without using linear transformation or linear mapping

Comment: The above will allow you to proceed which you were not able to do a moment ago.